# write a function in JES that will distinguish type of file is chosen

Tags: jes

"Write a function that will obtain a file name (using pickAFile), and then recognise if it is a picture or a sound file, or even some other file type. The file should then be interpreted as either a picture, if its type is jpg (then print an appropriate message, then exit) or a sound, if its type is wav (then print an appropriate message, then exit), and if it is neither a picture nor a sound file, then an error message must be printed. This error message should include the type of the file (or the lack of a type, e.g. a file name that might not have a period in it, e.g. ducksjpg). Remember that file types can be 2, 3, 4 or even more letters long! "

So this is what I have figured out so far and it works:

```
def sortoutfiles():
 f= pickAFile()
 print f
 filename=f
 if filename.endswith (".jpg"):
   print "It's a picture"
 if filename.endswith (".wav"):
   print " It's a sound"
 else:
   print"Oops! Did not choose a picture or a sound file"
```

For some reason the program doesnt work when I try to use rfind-get error message-invalid syntax on line 5

```
def sortoutfiles():
   f= pickAFile()
   print f
   filename=f  
   if p=filename.rfind('.jpg'):
      print "It's a picture"
   if filename=f.rfind(".wav"):
      print " It's a sound"
   else:
      print"Oops! Did not choose a picture or a sound file"
here
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong in writing the program using rfind?

Comment: Break it into the separate tasks, and then research how to complete each task separately. Solve the first task, then research the next task and add that functionality in to your code. Rinse and repeat until you've completed all of the tasks. If you get stuck along the way, you can explain the problem you're having, *include the relevant code you're having difficulty with*, and ask a specific question. If you can't get started at all, ask your instructor for help.

Answer (score 0):

Apco 1P00?

Use rfind to figure out the file extension

```
f = pickAFile()
p = f.rfind('.jpg') #finds if the file ends in .jpg
s = f.rfind('.wav') #finds if the file ends in .wav
length = len(f) #finds the length of the file name
```

Use this as a foundation and go from here using if statements.

Recall the last lab.

```
>>> testString = 'abc DEf ghi ihg uVW xyz'
>>> print testString.find('k')
-1           #"Not found" can't be 0, so result is -1
```